# Use different transport for domain forwarding in Exim4

Tags: debian, exim, amazon-ses

I am attempting to configure exim4 under Debian 6 or 7 as follows:

- For mails being forwarded for a "virtual" domain, send directly via SMTP
- For all other mails, send via Amazon SES

The first bullet seems necessary because SES will not allow the sending of a message whose "From" address does not match a valid configured domain for that AWS account (if anybody does know a way to do this with SES, that would be a preferred solution, although I am pretty sure it is not possible).

So, right now this system works fine with SES; everything sends correctly, exim is configured correctly, etc. From that point, I defined a some new virtual domain I'd like to forward for, for example in `/etc/exim4/virtual/example.com`:

```
user : user@example.org
```

I then created a new router, for example `/etc/exim4/conf.d/router/090_exim4-config_virtual_redirect` containing:

```
sender_redirect:
  driver = redirect
  domains = dsearch;/etc/exim4/virtual
  data = ${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim4/virtual/$domain}}
```

So far, this works fine -- exim attempts to relay messages addressed to `user@example.com` to `user@example.org` instead, but it fails because of the SES restriction mentioned above.

At this point, I want this router to send messages directly server-to-server, without affecting the sending of any other mails on the server.

Is this possible? I have a feeling there is one small addition I am missing here, but I haven't been able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out, and it turns out the solution was pretty simple. I used a configuration directive called `redirect_router` ([read about it here](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-generic_options_for_routers.html)) which tells Exim to start processing the next address generated by the current router with the specified router, allowing it to skip over any preceding routers in sequence.

I then defined my router structure as:

1. Amazon SES router
2. redirect router
3. default router chain (starting with `dnslookup_relay_to_domains` in Debian's default config)

So then my redirect router looked like:

```
sender_redirect:
  driver = redirect
  redirect_router = dnslookup_relay_to_domains
  domains = dsearch;/etc/exim4/virtual 
  data = ${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim4/virtual/$domain}}
```

It's also necessary to edit the `/etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf` file to make sure that `example.com` is listed as a local domain, like so (only showing the relevant lines):

```
dc_eximconfig_configtype='internet'
dc_other_hostnames='server.hostname.com;example.com'
dc_local_interfaces='0.0.0.0'
```

The `internet` value tells exim to behave as an internet site that communicates with other servers directly rather than through only a smarthost. It is necessary to be able to send and receive mail directly via SMTP.

The `0.0.0.0` tells Exim to bind to all IPv4 interfaces (the default is just to `127.0.0.1` which will not allow the server to receive mail from remote hosts). I am not sure if there is a better/more secure setting there, but I didn't want to specify an actual external IP since it may change in the EC2 environment.

Once all of that is done, you can do a `/etc/init.d/exim4 restart` to pick up the changes and everything should work.

Hopefully this helps somebody out; I have no idea if this is the "right" or "best" way to do this, but it seems to be working perfectly for my purposes.